# Testing factory inside controller shows error is not a function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Need help in testing the below function in a controller.

**getEmployeeList** is a self calling function in controller to load the data in ui when the controller loads, it is dependent on a factory, after writing the below code in controller all the current tests are failing
with the below error  "**employeeService.employeeList is not a function**.

```
$scope.getEmployeeList = function () {

                        employeeService.employeeList().then(function (result) {
                            angular.forEach(result.results, function (item) {
                                $scope.employees.push({eId:item.id,eName:item.name});
                            });                            
                        });
                    };

$scope.getEmployeeList();
```

Inside factory is a simple $http.get

```
 define([], function(){
    "use strict";
   var emplABC = function($http, $window, $q, $log, constants){

      var defered = $q.defer();

      var employeeList = function () {

               $http.get(constants.employeeApi, {withCredentials: true})
                   .success(function (data) {
                       defered.resolve(data);
                   }).error(function (ex) {
                   $log.error("abc err", {
                       workFlow: 'employee List',
                       message: 'An unexpected error ist of employees:' + ex
                   });
               });
               return defered.promise;
           };


      return {
          employeeList : employeeList
      };
   } ;

   emplABC.$inject = ['$http','$window', '$q', '$log'];

   return  emplABC;
});
```

pls suggest some examples...

Comment: can you how your factory code?

Comment: edited the question with factory method.

Comment: How does `enterpriseList` become the factory's `employeeList` method (assuming that's what you actually have)?

Comment: that was typo err. I have edited the question pls have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try remove var and use like:

employeeList = function () {